# FlashBuilder/Spark :: Mobile Project :: Change color of button in view actionbar

Tags: button, mobile, view, colors, flex-spark

FlashBuilder/Spark mobile project view action bar.

Currently if you set the chromeColor of a button in the actionbar it only shows up when on the press state of the button.  It does not change the color of the button default state.  I could not find any way to style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found that TransparentActionButtonSkin.as was overriding the drawBrackground function and specifically removing chromeColor and only allowing it to show on a the button down state.

I overrode that "little gem" with my own class.

```
package view_components
{
    import mx.core.mx_internal; 
    import spark.skins.mobile.TransparentActionButtonSkin;

    use namespace mx_internal;

    public class ActionbarColoredButton extends TransparentActionButtonSkin
    {
        public function ActionbarColoredButton()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function drawBackground(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {
            // omit super.drawBackground() to drawRect instead
            // only draw chromeColor in down state (transparent hit zone otherwise)

            //NO, I want colored action buttons
            var chromeColor:uint = getStyle(fillColorStyleName);
            var chromeAlpha:Number = 1;

            graphics.beginFill(chromeColor, chromeAlpha);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
```